# Issue with triangle indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a page on our website that uses a Google Images style expanding box. I am trying to put an indicator on the expanded `<div>` so a user knows what information they are currently viewing. It is working almost perfectly. The only issue is that if you click a box that is not the first one right after the page loads, the triangle goes off of the css rules defined for it:

`.triangle { margin-left: 25px; }`

Each container that holds the image in a given row contains a class to identify which column it is is: one through six. I use this column class to set how far the left margin should be:

```
function getMarginLeft(obj) {
    if( obj.hasClass('first') ) {
        x = '25px';
    }
    ...
    else if ( obj.hasClass('sixth') ) {
        x = '605px';
    }

    return x;
}

$('.superbox-list').click(function() {
    var ml = getMarginLeft($(this));
    $(".triangle").css('margin-left',ml);
}
```

I am not sure why this gets ignored at first. Check it out at: http://wwwdev.cco.purdue.edu/about/ncp.shtml

For example: right after the page loads click the ALDI box. Triangle appears correctly. Click Bechtel. Works fine. Reload the page and click the Bechtel box first. The triangle appears under the ALDI box, but if you click another box immediately it goes to the proper location.

Thanks for the help!

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the triangle has not been inserted into the document yet, so the first time `$(".triangle").css('margin-left', ml)` runs, it applies to nothing.

So you can either move this line to be after the insert (line 93, `superbox.insertAfter(this)...`), or maybe change the line to `triangle.css('margin-left', ml)`, referring to the variable.

Comment: Thanks! Referring to the variable fixed it!